# Firestore security rules check if reference exists

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm wondering how I could check if a document value is a reference to another document and the document exists using firebase security rules.

What I tried:

```
function validate(document) {
    return exists(document.reference)
}

match /collection/{document} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
    allow create, update: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) && validate(request.resource.data);
}
```

As this didn't work, I tried to figure out what type `document.ref` is.
Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have any type of the listed ones here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/?authuser=0#data_types

I tried `path` as it's the most obvious one to work with exists.
I didn't expect it to work.
Another guess was maybe `map` or `string`.
Both were incorrect.

As I don't have a clue what this could be and there is nothing documented how I can convert the reference to a path, I now have to ask here.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

TL;DR:

I need to check using Firestore security rules whether a reference saved in a document is present and it exists in the database.

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? Also, just for clarification is the reference value on `request.resource.data.ref` or `request.resource.data.reference`? You reference it one way in the code and another in the description.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the code you are using to create/update the document? Also, could you remove the isAdmin call? just to isolate the validate function. And please also share the SDK version you are suing. I tried using the Web SDK and seems to be working for me, I'd be helpful to test using the same environment you are using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this line:

`allow create, update: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) && validate(request.resource.data)`

instead of calling "request.resource.data", you should just call "resource.data":

```
allow create, update: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid) && validate(resource.data)
```

As mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/?authuser=0#firestore-resource), the resource variable represent the Firestore document, whereas the "[request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/?authuser=0#request)" variable represents the request being made at that path, thus not containing information about the actual values in the document.

Give it a try and let me know if it doesn't work for your.

Comment: Have in mind that you're setting this rule to both create and update. When you're running a create operation, the resource.data will not contain any actual values in the document, thus the rule will fail. But the [`request.resource.data` Reference Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#request) mentions: "Fields not provided in the request which exist in the resource are added to `request.resource.data`". Which means it will contain the the actual values on both create and update.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes You are right, i tried reading the document to start testing this and forgot to test updating/creating the document.
Still seems to be working fine for me when having request.resource.data the only think I can think of is if he reference field is not being set correctly or that the current user is not an admin. I'm also not sure if this could be related to a specific SDK version

Comment: Thanks you both for the help, I will put here some more info :)

Comment: And I've tested this rule with several configurations and I probably also removed the isAdmin call :)

Comment: Ahh and I remembered that, removing all checks in the validate call which check if a reference exists worked so it's somehow of the wrong type :o

Answer (score 10):

You can check if the resource already exists by using `resource == null` or `resource != null`

Example:

```
allow write: if resource == null //Only can create, not update
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [`exists()` documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/?authuser=0#service_defined):

> The path provided must begin with `/databases/$(database)/documents`.

So you should change your validate function to:

```
function validate(document) {
    return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(document.reference))
}
```

Comment: Further down in the documentation for path [it says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/?authuser=0#path_2), "The path variable contains the full path. In this case, it begins with /projects/projectId/databases/(default)/documents/...". So it's confusing as to when the `/projects/projectId` part is needed as well.